# lightning-record-edit-form Error handling

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

How do we handle errors in `lightning-record-edit-form` when we encounter different types of errors? I'm observing distinct JSON structures for these errors. Currently, I'm encountering two different error types:

1. Duplicate Record Error:

```js
{
    "message": "An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.",
    "detail": "Use one of these records?",
    "output": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "constituentField": null,
                "duplicateRecordError": {
                    "matchResults": [
                        {
                            "apiName": "Opportunity_Case__c",
                            "isAllowSave": false,
                            "matchRecordIds": ["a6iD50000001kOEIAY"],
                            "matchRule": "Opportunity_Case_Matching",
                            "objectLabel": "Opportunity Case",
                            "objectLabelPlural": "Opportunity Cases",
                            "themeInfo": {
                                "color": "5ab0d2",
                                "iconUrl": "https://salesforce--qa.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/img/icon/t4v35/custom/custom27_120.png"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "errorCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
                    "field": null,
                    "fieldLabel": null,
                    "message": "Use one of these records?"
                }
            }
        ],
        "fieldErrors": {}
    }
}
```

2. Required Field Missing Error:

```js
{
    "message": "An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.",
    "detail": "Required fields are missing: [Related_Case__c]",
    "output": {
        "errors": [],
        "fieldErrors": {
            "Related_Case__c": [
                {
                    "constituentField": null,
                    "duplicateRecordError": null,
                    "errorCode": "REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING",
                    "field": "Related_Case__c",
                    "fieldLabel": "Related Case",
                    "message": "Required fields are missing: [Related_Case__c]"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

For handling the duplicate exception, I'm displaying a custom error using the following code:

```js
if (event.detail.output.errors[0].errorCode == "DUPLICATES_DETECTED") {
    const errorMsg = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Error!',
        message: 'Duplicate Case Found for this Opportunity.',
        variant: 'error'
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(errorMsg);
}
```

Now, for the required field error, I need to retrieve the error code using a different approach. Is there an easier way to obtain the error code so that I can customize the error message based on the type of error I receive?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle these errors is to use the `reduceErrors` method from [LWC Recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes). This will give you the right error message, no matter what the type is.

Example of how to use:

```
import { reduceErrors } from 'c/utils';
...

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
wiredRecord({error, data}) {
    if (error) {
        this.errorMessage = reduceErrors(this.error);
    } else if (data) {
        // Process record data
    }
}
```

If you need to customise the error further based on the type, you could amend the `reduceErrors` method to suit your needs.

There's more detail on error handling in this helpful article: [Error Handling Best Practices for Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/08/error-handling-best-practices-for-lightning-web-components)